# Add new row to asp .net grid view using button

Tags: .net, asp.net, gridview, asp.net-2.0

I am working in ASP .net 2.0. I am a learner. I have a grid view which has a button in it. Please find the asp mark up below

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <asp:GridView ID="myGridView" runat="server">
        <Columns>
            <asp:TemplateField>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Button CommandName="AddARowBelow" Text="Add A Row Below"   runat="server" />
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
</div>
</form>
```

Please find the code behind below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace GridViewDemo
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable("myTable");
            dt.Columns.Add("col1");
            dt.Columns.Add("col2");
            dt.Columns.Add("col3");
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3);
            dt.Rows.Add(1, 2, 3);
            myGridView.DataSource = dt;
            myGridView.DataBind();
        }

        protected void myGridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }
}
```

I was thinking that when I click the command button, it would fire the mygridview_rowcommand() but instead it threw an error as follows:

Invalid postback or callback argument.  Event validation is enabled using  in configuration or <%@ Page EnableEventValidation="true" %> in a page.  For security purposes, this feature verifies that arguments to postback or callback events originate from the server control that originally rendered them.  If the data is valid and expected, use the ClientScriptManager.RegisterForEventValidation method in order to register the postback or callback data for validation.

Can any one let me know on where I am going wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, try to disable event validation and see what the result is, since that is the obvious problem in your code.

```
<%@ Page EnableEventValidation="false" ...
```

However, **if you don't want to restort to such a hack**, do the following:

After that, delete the `OnCommand` event from the button's attributes, and add an `OnRowCommand` event to the `GridView` itself.

Example:

```
<asp:GridView OnRowCommand="myGridView_RowCommand">
    ...
</asp:GridView>
```

This should be the correct way of handling these commands.
The button must have a **specific** `CommandName` in order for it to work as intended.

[See this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowcommand.aspx) for possible values and more explanation of this issue. There is also a **working example** on that page, it is worth your time to check it out.

Comment: I did as you said. And then I did not get the error. But when I clicked the button, myGridView_RowCommand did not fire.

I actually added 

<pre>
asp:Button OnCommand="myGridView_RowCommand" ....
</pre>

and it worked.

Comment: @SARAVAN - by the way, in your code the `GridView` and the `myGridView_RowCommand` are not connected in any way.

Comment: asp:Button OnCommand="myGridView_RowCommand"

Look at the above code, I actually added it as soon as you replied to my question. Anyway I updated the code as well.

Comment: @SARAVAN - I now understand what your problem really is. Edited my answer for you.